# trigger click? autoload lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really don't understand jQuery, but I'm using a lightbox from [here](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/) and I want the first photo to open when the page loads.

When I used Fancybox before, I could do it with a trigger click and it would work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    });
    // Launch fancyBox on first element
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

So I tried to just do the same thing with lightGallery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lightGallery").lightGallery({
    }); 
    $("#lightGallery").eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

But it doesn't work

The whole thing is [here](http://staygold.ca/wood/tour.html) (I'm sure it's a huge mess, I'm just kind of fumbling my way through it).

I tried a few different solutions on here (window.load was one I think) But i don't understand it enough to know whether the solution isn't working or I'm just missing a '{' or some stupid thing

Answer (score 0):

`$('#lightGallery img:eq(0)').click()` should do it.